# How to define various Compare in priority_queue?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

My code below works fine:

```
auto cmp = [](int left, int right){ return left < right; };
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> mypq(cmp);

for (int n : {3, 1, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3}) {
    mypq.push(n);
}

while (!mypq.empty()) {
    cout << mypq.top() << ' ';
    mypq.pop();
}

// output: 4 3 3 2 1 1 0
```

But I want to set priority in different ways changing the body part of the lambda expression. For example, how can I give priority to odd numbers or square numbers? I tried some and get a runtime error probably because of the 'strict weak ordering'. Am I not supposed to do this with priority_queue in STL?

Comment: `return is_odd(left) < is_odd(right);` ?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the comparison functions that you tried?

Comment: And yes you have to respect strict weak ordering. An easy way is to transform your input in a way where you can have a direct call similar to `return f(lhs) < f(rhs)`.

Comment: `return std::make_tuple(left % 2, left) < std::make_tuple(right % 2, right);` This would put odd numbers ahead of even numbers, then within each group would sort numerically as usual.